# Make ENTER act like a button click in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a basic sign-in page using Bootstrap where a user enters an email address and password and then presses a "Sign-In" button to log into our online app.

The bootstrap button uses the "data-xxx-complete" text identifier to change the color and state of the button to "Authenticating..." after the user has clicked it.

I was able to use an event handler to trap the enter key and force a form submit, but what I really want to do is trap the enter key to make it act just like the user *clicking* the sign-in button so I get the "Authenticating..." state change on that element before the form submits.  This is important as sometimes the login process takes several seconds.

Here is the button:

```
echo "<div class='form-group' id='sendBtn1'>";
    echo "<div class='col-xs-3 text-left'>";
        echo "<button type='button' id='sendButton' class='btn btn-primary' autocomplete='off' data-complete-text='Authenticating...' onclick=\"$(this).button('complete');$(this).prop('disabled',true);J_action('signin');\" >";
        echo "Sign In";
        echo "</button>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

The `J_Action();` function called from the sign-in button just calls a simple JS routine that handle where and what to do next with the login.

The code to handle the keypress is in my header as follows:

```
    ...
    function checkSubmit(e) { 
        if(e && e.keyCode == 13) {
            J_action('signin');
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onKeyPress='return checkSubmit(event)'>
```

Is there a way to directly tell a button in bootstrap to change it's state?

I tried to add the same JS calls that were in the onClick event on the button itself to the event handler, but am not sure if using the ID name of the button in place of the `(this)` nomenclature is the right syntax.  This did not work for me to change the state of the button.

```
    ...
    function checkSubmit(e) { 
        if(e && e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(sendButton).button('complete');
            $(sendButton).prop('disabled',true);
            J_action('signin');
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onKeyPress='return checkSubmit(event)'>
```

Comment: you can check what is the item's class after you click on the button and then you can add that bootstrap class with jquery

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by this or how to go about this.  Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just need to use the jquery selector correctly. You select in a CSS-like style using selectors.

So to select the `id="sendButton"` you would need a # symbol to signify that you want the item with id of sendButton: `$('#sendButton')`. So you would want to change your code to this

```
$('#sendButton').button('complete');
$('#sendButton').prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Adding the "#" symbol seems logical, but as soon as I refresh the page, Chrome developer console shows it is throwing an error: "SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#'".  And Clicking enter now does not work at all and even clicking on the button now freezes the screen on the "Authenticating..." ??

Comment: Hmm, did you try it with quotes?

Comment: Bah, I spoke too soon.  I think my eyesight must be going.  Yes, the single quotes fixed it.  Can't believe I missed that.  Thanks so much for the tip!